# Wordpress Search only Title (But not exact)

Tags: wordpress, search

I've thousand of woocommerce product in my website and my wordpress search working very slow. So that I've tried to search only in title to speed up my search and I found this:

```
function __search_by_title_only( $search, $wp_query )
{
global $wpdb;

if ( empty( $search ) )
return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query

$q = $wp_query->query_vars;
$n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';

$search =
$searchand = '';

foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
$term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );

$search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$term}[[:>:]]')";

$searchand = ' AND ';
}

if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
$search = " AND ({$search}) ";
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
$search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
}

return $search;
}

add_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 1000, 2 );
```

But it searching exact word with uppercase / lowercase sensitive and I do not want that. For example, I've a product with name "795PA" and when I searched "795pa" returning no result. How can I fix that? Ideas?

Comment: have you tried to convert everything to lowercase while searching?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but Some of my post titles uppercase and some of lowercase I can't use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the differance but that little code fixed my problem. Here is the fix:

```
//Limit Search to Post Titles Only
function ni_search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( empty( $search ) )
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query
    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';
    $search =
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
        $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }
    if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'ni_search_by_title_only', 500, 2 );
```

I don't know can I share links here but [nathan ingram](https://nathaningram.com/restricting-wordpress-search-to-titles-only/) shared that.